# CSS Overflow problems with picture header and list

Tags: html, css, overflow, responsive

Is this possible using css...I also tried the use of absolute and relative... but it only works with left:0 and right: 0... but the height bottom and top is almost like 0... it doesn't take any value or scalable...

while doing some test and experimenting in inspect element...( i forgot what i do...cant recreate )
i was able to do some ellipses but with the use of 100% width which is still not the result im looking for because it included the left part or the picture part of the code in equating the width... it result in .../ellipses but it is still overflow... need help please.

Thank you in advance

```
<!--
    I Want Responsive :(
    Overall Box is 330px
    So The Header and Items must be around 280
    Picture is 50px only
    Items must be scalable in height... it can be more like e.g 20items

    PROBLEM
----------------------------
| Pic | Header             |
| tu  | ------------------ |
| re  | Item 1             |
|     | Item 2             |
|     | Item 3333333333333333333333333 | <- Overflow
|     | Item 4             |
|     | Item 5             |
----------------------------

    EXPECTED RESULT
----------------------------
| Pic | Header             |
| tu  | ------------------ |
| re  | Item 1             |
|     | Item 2             |
|     | Item 3333333333... | <- TextOverflow
|     | Item 4             |
|     | Item 5             |
----------------------------
-->
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uv98zgbk/

is this possible? if possible is i rather avoid the use of calc in css like 100% - 50px...ocd problems

Comment: So, what you are looking for, is for the text to wrap? If that's what you are after then you should avoid using flexbox and also take a look at the `word-wrap` css property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this work? Setting the overflow on the anchor tags instead?

```css
.container {
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
overflow:hidden;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.list {
  flex-grow: 2;
  max-width:100%;
}

.list-container {
  max-width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

a {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="picture">
    Picture
  </div>
  <div class="list">
    Header
    <div class='list-container'>
      <a href="#">Item 1</a>
      <a href="#">Item 2</a>
      <a href="#">Item 333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333</a>
      <a href="#">Item 4</a>
      <a href="#">Item 5</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no, there is a problem when you lengthen the text like..
Item 33333333333333 make it more Item 3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333

the problems shows. it out of bounds and stretches longer

Comment: @user3492648 I just edited the snippet, adding some max-width properties